# Sbt/Activator not running all tests in Play2 java project

Tags: java, junit, sbt, playframework-2.3

SBT/Activator are not running all of the tests in my project. Is there something I'm missing?

Eg this is a test:

```
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void simpleCheck() {
        int a = 1 + 1;
        assertThat(a).isEqualTo(2);
    }

    @Test
    public void renderTemplate() {
        assert(1==1);
    }


}
```

It's in the test folder, has all attributes junit expects, yet does not run when I execute 'sbt test' or 'activator test'. It only seems to run the files that end with IntegrationTest...
Is there something I need to do differently?
Can't find any solution here.

Answer (score 12):

'activator clean test' fixed this for me.
Unsure why - I've worked with sbt for a long time with scala and have never seen this.

Comment: Even after an year, the issue is still exist and the resolution is same :)

Comment: Experiencing the same problem...and was resolved by the same issue. Thanks! I notice that sbt clean test works also... but the "sbt clean testOnly ..." and "activator clean testOnly ..." seems to ignore my request to only test a certain class and just runs them all. Go figure.